# Why does HTML treat 2 and 3-byte characters the same, but not 4-byte?

Tags: html, unicode, byte, maxlength

I'm doing some GUI work for a website and using the "maxlength" attribute for some text inputs, some of which may contain Unicode characters.

Say I've got a text field with maxlength = 50 and I fill it full of 2-byte Unicode characters (UTF-16). I can get 50 characters in the text field.

I can also do the same with 3-byte characters. 50 of them.

I can only get 25 4-byte characters in the field, however. Stands to reason, since it's twice as many bytes, but why does it still respond normally when using 3-byte characters? How is the extra byte handled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unicode characters can generally be encoded in either UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32 ([see their faq](https://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html)). Your usage of 2, 3 & 4 byte characters tells me you're working from a UTF-8 perspective.

However, the maxlength attribute is [defined as the maximum number of UTF-16 code units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/maxlength), not number of bytes. Each UTF-16 code unit is two bytes.

A 2-byte UTF-8 character will be a single UTF-16 code unit. A 3-byte UTF-8 character will also be a single UTF-16 code unit. However, a 4-byte UTF-8 character represents a Unicode character greater than 0xFFFF. UTF-16 represents this as two code units (called surrogate pairs, see faq linked above).

Comment: Cheers, I was struggling to understand code points. Surrogate pairs I'm aware of but 3-bytes were tripping me up.